# laravel - if/elseif - weird error in layout

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel

I have in my footer partial in layout this code:

```
@if(isset(Session::get('errormessage'))
  <div style="background-color:#ff3300; padding:4px; color:white; font-size:80%" {{Session::get('errormessage') }}</div>

@elseif(isset(Session::get('okmessage'))
  <div style="background-color:#00ff00; padding:4px; color:white; font-size:80%"> {{ Session::get('okmessage') }}</div>

@endif
```

But this returns in HTML this:

```
<?php if: ?>(isset(Session::get('errormessage'))
```

and error:

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('

What do I do wrong? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@if(Session::has('errormessage'))
  <div style="background-color:#ff3300; padding:4px; color:white; font-size:80%" {{Session::get('errormessage') }}</div>

@elseif(Session::has('okmessage'))
  <div style="background-color:#00ff00; padding:4px; color:white; font-size:80%"> {{ Session::get('okmessage') }}</div>

@endif
```

instead of isset use Session::has('variable')

Answer (score 0):

> @if(isset(Session::get('errormessage'))

You miss closing bracket.

Comment: thanks, but now im gettting error: Can't use function return value in write context

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parenteses. You have three `(` but only two `)`. Same on your `@elseif`.

```
@if(isset(Session::get('errormessage')))
  <div style="background-color:#ff3300; padding:4px; color:white; font-size:80%" {{Session::get('errormessage') }}</div>

@elseif(isset(Session::get('okmessage')))
  <div style="background-color:#00ff00; padding:4px; color:white; font-size:80%"> {{ Session::get('okmessage') }}</div>

@endif
```

Also, you don't need to use `isset` on `Session::get`. If you don't have a session variable with your selected key `null` will be returned. It's enough to just use `@if(Session::get('key'))`.

```
Session::get('i-dont-exists'); // returns null
```